# Why does for...in fail gracefully but for...of throw an Exception?

Tags: javascript, foreach, ecmascript-6

Why is it that

```
for (let e in null) void e
```

fails gracefully, but that

```
for (let e of null) void e
```

throws a `TypeError`?
Doesn't this result in an inconsistency?

Comment: This discussion seems relevant: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/will-for-var-a-of-null-throw-an-error .

Comment: Thanks, indeed it answers the question, very interesting read.

Answer (score 6):

`for...of` only works on *iterable* objects (i.e. objects implementing [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols)) which `null` is not either of these. Whereas `for...in` works on all values.

Comment: `null instanceof Object` gives `false`

Comment: yes, but `typeof null` is `object` - clearly nonsense.  `for .. of`'s behavior of throwing an exception (because null is not iterable) is far more graceful than `for ..in`'s apparent claim that `null` is an empty `object` with no prototype chain.  By the way,  check out 'Appendix A: Aweful Parts', page 103, in Doug Crockford's classic book on the unfortunate classification of `null` as an object with the `typeof operator`.

Comment: @ Peter Varga Everything in Javascript is object (including `null`).

Comment: @hindmost: No. Primitive values (boolean, number, string, undefined, null, symbol)  are *not* objects. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types

Comment: @PeterVarga: JavaScript performs [autoboxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming)#Autoboxing) for primitive types/values that have an object equivalent.